# Почему не центрирует текст с img в safari?

Tags: css

```
        &-line {
        display: flex;
        width: 116px;
        margin: 15px 0;
        align-items: center;
      &-icon {
            width: 20px; 
        }
        &-lnk {
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: Helvetica-Neue;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 400;
            letter-spacing: 0.24px;
            text-transform:  capitalize;
            transition: .4s;
            margin-left: 5px;
            &:hover {
              transition: .4s;
              color:#c8ac6e;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: вы приведите нормальный сниппет с версткой и скомпилированными стиялми

Comment: -webkit- надо добавить ко всему что имеет flex в css а лучше весь css прогнать через autoprefixer